# High pass filter in Julia

Tags: audio, julia, filtering, signal-processing

I'm recording live audio in 5 second clips with Julia and want to cut out all sounds below a certain frequency. This is my record script so far:

```
using PortAudio, SampledSignals, LibSndFile, FileIO, Dates

stream = PortAudioStream("HDA Intel PCH: ALC285 Analog (hw:0,0)")

buf = read(stream, 5s)

while true
    save(string("recording_", Dates.format(now(), "yyyymmdd_HHMMSS"), ".wav"), buf, Fs = 48000)
```

How do I filter out all sound below e.g. 10kHz? I've been looking at the `Highpass` function from the `DSP` package but I don't quite understand how to apply it correctly.

Comment: N.B.: you will get better performance if you use `dateformat"yyyymmdd_HHMMSS"`, as it will only have to convert the format string to a `DateFormat` once, at compile time, instead of in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using DSP

"""
    highpassfilter(signals, fs, cutoff, order=4)
Apply high pass filter to signals, return filtered data
"""
function highpassfilter(signals, fs, cutoff, order=4)
    wdo = 2.0 * cutoff / fs
    filth = digitalfilter(Highpass(wdo), Butterworth(order))
    filtfilt(filth, signals)
end
```